# Is there a way to represent a measurement with multiple values as a observation?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I got a problem that I have some measurement data ( like Echo measurements), that can potentially have multiple values associated with it. In other words, you have a single measurement, but multiple values associated.

Is there a standard way to represent multiple values for a single measurement as a Observation?If so, what is the best way?

I notice that under observation, you can have multiple components, should I put my LOINC code for my measurement just at observation level and put each value at component level? Or I have to use extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what your data looks like but here are a couple of patterns:

There is sampledData Datatype that can be used for datastreams like an EKG
[example](http://build.fhir.org/observation-example-sample-data.html)

If you have discrete values that are all interpreted together with an observation ( they can't stand alone as independent observations) the using components with an `Observation.code`= code,  `Observation.value[x]` is empty , `Observation.component.code`= code,  `Observation.component.value[x]`= result value.  [here](http://build.fhir.org/observation-example-1minute-apgar-score.html) is an example of this pattern.

In some cases you will have an `Observation.value[x]` as well.

Note `Observation.component.code` is required for each component.

For grouping indpendent observations together using component is not appropriate.  This grouping is done using `DiagnosticReport.result`  or `Observation.related`.  The DiagnosticReport  resource which typically used for reporting diagnostics in responce to an order.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! use component does sound feasible. But one thing is that the data I have are just simple duplicates of the same measurement. So probably I can not find different code for the component vs observation.